# AngluarJS Unit Test - Undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I am trying to learn how to unit test within angular. Unit testing my controllers to start with then my services.

I have started off with a basic test.

Controller code:

```
angular.module('app')
  .controller('TestCtrl', function ($rootScope,$scope,fileLoader,ngProgress) {
 $scope.test= [];
    $scope.init = function(){
      fileLoader.getFile("test")
        .then(function(res){
          //Success
          console.log(res);
          $scope.test= res;
        }, function(err){
          //Error
        });

      ngProgress.complete();
    }

    $scope.init();
$scope.title = "Test";
  });
```

Test code:

```
describe('Controller: TestCtrl', function () {

  // load the controller's module
  beforeEach(module('app'));

  var TestCtrl,
    scope,test;
  test = {};
  test.getFile = function(name) {
    return [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Test",
        "imgName": "Test.png"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Test1",
        "imgName": "Test1.png"
      }];
  };


  // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
  beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    TestCtrl= $controller('TestCtrl', {
      $scope: scope,
      fileLoader : test
    });
  }));

  it('should have the correct title', function () {
    expect(scope.title).toBe("Test");
  });
});
```

And I can't understand why I am getting the following error:

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating
>   'fileLoader.getFile("test")
>             .then')     undefined

Is there any way once this is resolved I can lay all my mocking out in a separate file e.g. my fileLoader mock and just inject it that way?

I don't understand how I am injecting it but yet it is undefined.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> And I can't understand why I am getting the following error:

you defined

```
fileLoader.getFile("test")
   .then(function(res){
```

so getFile() should return a promise which could be resolved, but you return a simple array with two objects inside

```
 test.getFile = function(name) {
   return [
   {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Test",
    "imgName": "Test.png"
   },
   {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Test1",
    "imgName": "Test1.png"
   }]
```

refactor one side. Use defers or handle the array result.

Comment: How would I handle the promise on the unit test side?

Comment: Surely that would still showed as defined as I am returning something just not the right thing?

Comment: you call "then" after getFile()..."then" is undefined because getFile() returned a array... undefined is not a function.. 

for "defer" take a look at angular $q [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#testing)